# retrieving values from different java files in one project

Tags: java, user-interface, reference, project, getter-setter

I'm having some difficulties in retrieving values from one java class into another. I have this Login.java, it has a userIDField which is a textfield that allows the user to enter his/her userID. I added a getter in this Login.java.

```
public String getUserID(){
   return userIDField.getText();
}
```

then I have a AddSale.java that calls the getUserID method to get the userID entered by the user. I'm accessing this via the confirmAddSales button.

```
private Login log = new Login();

private void confirmAddSalesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    String sample = log.getUserID();
    System.out.println(sample+"<------------------check if sample is working");
}
```

but there is no result for the String "sample" in the AddSale.java, please help in resolving this. thank you.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you're calling that method?

Comment: yes. @MrLore. I added this in my Login.java to check if the method is really working.  
private void logInButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        System.out.println(getUserID()+"<--------------checker");
        AddSales salesConfirm = null;
}

this perfectly outputs the result I wanted.

Comment: Are they both referring to the same instance of `Login`?

Comment: @DavidConrad I think my mistake here is making a new instance of Login in AddSale.java. But when I remove "new Login()". The program results a nullpointerexception. Any suggestion on What approach I can do for this?

Comment: Pass the `Login` object that's used in your GUI into `AddSale` via its constructor. What classes are these in, and how (or when) are they constructed?

Comment: i'm still new to java, can you please give some examples?

Comment: @DavidConrad I've read through some threads in this site about your suggestion in using a constructor. and it worked! thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't see your request for an example. If the GUI is in class `Main` which is also where your `main` method is, and it creates both the text field and the `AddSale` object, you could do something like this:

```
public class Main() {
    JTextField userIDField;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        userIDField = new JTextField();
        Login login = new Login(userIDField);
        AddSale addSale = new AddSale(userIDField);
        Frame frame = new JFrame();
        // ... and so on ...
        button.addActionListener(addSale);
    }
}

public class AddSale implements ActionListener {
    private final Login login;

    public AddSale(Login login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    private void confirmAddSalesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        String sample = login.getUserID();
        System.out.println(sample+"<------------------check if sample is working");
    }
}
```

This way, the `Login` object, the `AddSale` object, and any other parts of your program are all referring to the same `Login` object and text field. This may not quite be the right relationship since you haven't told us anything about how your classes get created, or what they're called, but this is the general approach.